# How to close main window while doing other tasks in a clicked button event?

Tags: rust, gtk

I'm trying to recreate [this Python project in Rust](https://github.com/ShareXin/ShareXin). The Python version uses PyQt5, but the Ruby version uses GTK. When using Rust or Ruby, I don't know how to properly execute the "Tweeting" code when the user presses "Tweet".

The button the user presses is called "send", and this code is called when it's pressed:

```
send.connect_clicked(move |_| {
    let sent: Option<String> = TextBuffer::get_text(
        &TextView::get_buffer(&text).unwrap(),
        &TextBuffer::get_start_iter(&TextView::get_buffer(&text).unwrap()), 
        &TextBuffer::get_end_iter(&TextView::get_buffer(&text).unwrap()), false);
    let actual = sent.unwrap();
    println!("Text: {}", actual);
    let toot = Command::new("t").output()
        .expect("Nope");
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&toot.stdout));
    Notification::new().summary("Sent")
        .body(&actual).show().unwrap();
    gtk::main_quit();
});
```

Whenever the user presses it though, the window freezes until the code is done running, then the main window quits.

How would I correctly close the window and execute this code?  It's probably very simple but I've barely properly researched functions. Bad habit from writing Python scripts.

Comment: The code inside the callback is, probably, taking too long and the UI freezes until it finishes and then Gtk can resume and close the window. Maybe you should use threads or async methods.

Comment: @JoséFonte I figured out how to correctly use threads with GTK's idle_add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly close the main window and do other tasks, I used `idle_add` from glib.

```
thread::spawn(move || {
    glib::idle_add(move || {
        toot(tweet);
        gtk::main_quit();
        Continue(false)
    });
});
```

Comment: Spawning a thread is no longer needed apparently. https://github.com/ShareXin/ShareXin/blob/master/src/dialog.rs#L120